# Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d_5 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When trying to train my model, I get

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d_5 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, None, 180, 180, 16)
```

My image shape is `(32, 180, 180, 3)`, which is 4 dimensional. I am also shuffling and batching my training dataset: `train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(100).batch(4)`

**Network**

```
num_classes = 101

model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])
```

What is causing this traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original images seem to be already batched. If you batch a 4D tensor it will output a tensor of shape:

```
(4, 32, 180, 180, 3)
```

I suggest you do not batch the images a second time. Since you're using `image_dataset_from_directory` with `batch_size=32`, you don't need to use `.batch(4)`.

Comment: What that would mean is delete the `batch_size=32` argument from my `image_dataset_from_directory` function, correct? I'm very much a beginner in this regard.

Comment: No in this case, you should remove the `batch(4)` instead

Comment: While this fixed my main issue, `batch()` was initially suggested because of the overall low performance when training the model, I have tried applying **caching**, which quickly caused an "out of memory" exception, and increasing the number of convolutional layers. Do you have any more suggestions which can be used for speeding up the training process? My dataset is consisted of 101.000 images.

Comment: But batching is already done with size 32. Your mistake was batching the batches